# Showing currently logged in facebook user's avatar

Tags: facebook

Is that possible with facebook api, to show the currently logged in facebook user's face on a webpage (like facebook faces, but with the current user only)? Without requiring the user to accept an application etc, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. A user has to grant the app permission to access their data. See [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/) for more info on permissions.

Comment: Nevertheless I've seen sites using Facebook comments and in such a situations your avatar gets shown even when you did not grant permissions for that... maybe some workaround can be done for that...